# Finding an exact match of a dynamic text string within a specific cell with instr function

Tags: excel, vba

I created a loop that looks through a table and inserts the values (if existent) in specific cells in another table

I need the text values once found to be inserted in `Sheet7.Cells(r, "G")` but only if the exact text string doesn't exist there anymore. The problem is that the wording of the text values is very similar but they are different.
My current code doesn't add some of them presumably because it thinks they are already inserted in the cell since some words repeat. Is there any way to solve this ?

[image: data sample]
[image: result with instr condition]

```
Do While k < 119 And r < 118

        access = Sheet3.Cells(i, k)

            If access <> "" Then

              If Sheet7.Cells(r, "G") <> "" And InStr(Sheet7.Cells(r, "G"), access) = 0 Then
              Sheet7.Cells(r, "G") = Sheet7.Cells(r, "G") & vbNewLine & access
              Else: Sheet7.Cells(r, "G") = access
              End If

              If Sheet7.Cells(r, "F") <> "" Then
              Sheet7.Cells(r, "F") = Sheet7.Cells(r, "F") & vbNewLine & Sheet3.Cells(i, "C")
              Else: Sheet7.Cells(r, "F") = Sheet3.Cells(i, "C")
              End If

          End If

         k = k + 1
         r = r + 1 

        Loop
```

Comment: Can you provide example of your data (or sheet) and the expected result?

Comment: This is a list of possible results: FUEL TANK ENTRY  
FUEL TANK ENTRY  
FUEL TANK ENTRY  
FUEL TANK ENTRY  
FUEL TANK ENTRY  
FUEL TANK ENTRY  
FUEL TANK ENTRY  
FUEL TANK ENTRY  
FUEL TANK ENTRY  
CENTRAL FUEL TANK  
WING FUEL TANK  
WING FUEL TANK  
WING FUEL TANK  
WING FUEL TANK  
WING FUEL TANK   
WING FUEL TANK  
CENTER FUEL TANK LH  
MAIN FUEL TANK LH  
CENTER FUEL TANK RH  
MAIN FUEL TANK RH  
LH FUEL TANKS OPENED  
RH FUEL TANKS OPENED  
For example I need to avoid entering "FUEL TANK ENTRY" multiple times in the cell

Comment: That's not a very helpful format.

Comment: I added a couple of screen shots to the question to visualize it better - please follow the links "data sample" and "result with instr function"

Comment: From what I can see, if the value already exists in the cell, your code will overwrite the current cell value to just the current value (that already exists in the cell) wiping out any other values that existed. Add an **`OR`** to your main `If` condition to check if the cell already contains values